# getStaticProps: cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on online shop project using next.js. I want to get list of lots in each category. I have category page in category[title] folder(category[title]\index.tsx) and I'm using dynamic route for each category by using getStaticProps in category page. When I write localhost/category/[title](title is dynamic for example: furniture or electronic) in the address bar, I receive this error:

> 

TypeError: cannot convert undefined or null to object
this error happened while generating the page. any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window

> 

This is my folder structure:

[image]

And this is my category page(category[title]\index.tsx)

```
import React from 'react'
import {getCategories,getLotsInCategory} from "../../../utils/firebase"

import { GetStaticPaths,GetStaticProps } from 'next';
 const Category = ({lotsInCategory}:{lotsInCategory:any[]}) => {
  return (
    <div>index</div>
  )
}

export const getStaticPaths:GetStaticPaths= async()=>{
    let response:any;
   
    let paths:Array<any>=[]
    try{
    // getCategories() is a data fetcher that fetches categories from firebase api and it works perfectly (tested in another component)
          response= await getCategories();
          paths= await response.map((el:any)=>{params:{title:el.categoryTitle.toString()}})
         
    }
    catch(er){
  
    }
     
    return {
      paths ,

      fallback: false, // can also be true or 'blocking'
    }
  }
export const getStaticProps:GetStaticProps=async(context:any)=>{
  
   let lotsInCategory:any[]=[];
  try{
// getLotsInCategory is a data fetcher method that fetches lots in each category from database api and it works perfect in another components! 
        lotsInCategory= await getLotsInCategory(context.params.title)
  }
  catch(er){
   console.log(er)
   
  }
  
  
    return {
      props: {lotsInCategory},
       revalidate:2
      
    }
  }
export default Category;
```

Update:

Full error message:
[image]

Update2:
I converted response to json in getStaticPaths:

```
export const getStaticPaths:GetStaticPaths= async()=>{
    let response:any;
   
    let paths:Array<any>=[]
    try{
          response= await getCategories();
              //coverting to json line below is very important!
          await response.json()
          paths= await response.map((el:any)=>{params:{title:el.categoryTitle.toString()}})
         
    }
    catch(er){
  
    }
     
    return {
      paths ,

      fallback:`blocking`, // can also be true or 'blocking'
    }
  }
```

Now it's working when fallback is blocking! But I receive 404 error when fallback is false what shall I do to make it work when fallback is false?

Comment: use [title].js instead of creating a folder named [title].

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (if I'm please someone let me know) when using ISR you should be setting `fallback` to either `true` or `blocking`.

Comment: You don't need the await in `await response.map(...)`. Can you show us the `getCategories` function?

Comment: @juliomalves getCategories is data fetcher of firebase and it works in other components (I tested) ```const getCategories=async()=>{
  try{
 
    const response=await getDocs(CategoriesCol)
      
        const categoriesList=response.docs.map(doc=>doc.data())
        
       
       
        console.log(categoriesList)
          return categoriesList;
  
  
  
        
    }
   catch(er){
    console.log(er)
    return er
   }
   ```